# Can I change my app from free to paid or from paid to free any time?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am about to submit an app to the app store for approval. I have a question regarding the app price.

Can I change the app from paid to free or from free to paid at any time? I have noticed that some paid apps have a promotion were the app is free for a limited time and I am considering using the same strategy if I can research it enough .

If I first write a free app and it's approved by App Store, can I sometime later change it to a paid app?

If I can do so, how does app store process the update? For example, if a user downloads my app when it's free can they update the app later when it is no longer free?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can change the price whenever you like. When a user downloads the app, whether it is paid or free, they get updates for free. They never have to pay again unless you add an in-app purchase into your app.

Comment: ***** IT SHOULD BE VERY CAUTIOUSLY NOTED THAT CHANGING FROM PAID TO FREE WILL RESET YOUR APP'S RANKING (at least it did for me in 2010...) I WOULD DO MORE RESEARCH FIRST! (changing from paid of 1 value to paid of another non-zero value doesn't affect the rank though)

Comment: i have maid my free app to paid app and now my status is pending contract.How much time it will take to release and what other process should i undergo???

Comment: @sujay Have you filled out your paid apps contract? Go to iTunes Connect > Contracts, Tax, and Banking.

Comment: Does changing from free to paid reset the ratings?

Comment: @Bashevis No, the ratings remain, even when the app is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it any time from your **App Store connect** setting. Have a look. Simply go to your **App Store connect** and select your **app** after that go to **pricing and availability** then simply change the *current price* to **FREE** and **save** your settings within *1-2 days* your changes will be reflected to App Store automatically.

[Check Out The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOx1P.jpg)

Comment: So no need to re-submit app for review? I already have inapp purchase but by mistake in app store connect selected my in app purchase in pricing information rather than selecting the free option. So no code changes is needed here.